# RSSへクローリングして記事収集がされない。

Tags: サーバー管理

他サイトから自サイトのRSSへクローリングしてもらい記事収集をしてもらっていたのですが、数日前からできなくなりました。

クローリング元に確認したところ、『Firewall等でアクセス拒否やサーバーでIP制限をかけてないか？』とのことでサーバー側等に確認してもIP制限をかけておらず、念のためクローリング元のIPをホワイトリストに入れてもらいました。

それでも改善がされません。RSSフィードのURLも間違っておりませんし、サーバー負荷でもありません。
原因がわからず困っております。
考えられる原因や、調査方法をご教示いただける人がおりましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。

- 使用PC:mac
- 使用サーバー：mixhost

Comment: クローリング元のサーバから直接（クローラーなどを使わずに）RSSのエンドポイントにアクセスすることはできますか？

Comment: 早速のご返信ありがとうございます！
クローリング元に問い合わせて対応してもらう様にいたします！
アドバイスいただきまして心強いです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12205643287